# selenium grid is not starting more than 5 sessions

Tags: automation, automated-tests, selenium-grid, ios-ui-automation

**I have done grid setup as follows:**

**Hub:** iMAC

**Started with:** 
java -jar Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub

**Node1:**
Win8 system

**Started with:** 
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.103:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig Node1.json

**Node2:**
Win10 system

**Started with:** 
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.103:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig Node2.json

The contents of the json is as follows:

```
    {
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "platform": "WINDOWS",
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 10,
    "port": 5557,
    "host": ip address of node1,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": ip address of hub
  }
}
```

Hub and nodes are started correctly. When i run a testng suite with 20 tests in the suite xml, with thread-count="10"

I see only 5 sessions are triggered,

- 3 on Node1
- 2 on Node2

**Expected/Want to achieve:**
10 sessions should be triggered, 5 on each nodes.

I tried the same setup with different versions of selenium server standalone, no luck though!!!

Please let me know if i'm doing any configuration mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce your problem. Here's what I have.

Hub started using the command :

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub`

Node #1 started using the command :

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodev2.json`

Node #2 started using the command :

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodev2.json -port 5556`

The contents of the node configuration file `nodev2.json` is as below :

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "maxInstances": 10,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "maxSession": 10
    }
}
```

At this point, I have a hub which has 2 nodes and each of the nodes can support 10 concurrent sessions at any given point in time.

I now run the below shell script (which would try to create 21 sessions). The script will stall and not exit, at the 21st attempt of creating a new session, because the 21st session is going to go into the Hub's waiting queue. You can confirm that there are 20 chrome sessions consumed by opening up the Grid console : http://localhost:4444/grid/console

The shell script can look like below :

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
for number in {1..21}
do
    curl -i \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -X POST -d '{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome"}}' \
    http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session
    echo "Created session " $counter
    let counter++
done
```

Comment: Thanks Krishnan,

Will try to use this shell script and node configuration json.
I will confirm if i am able to launch 20 parallel sessions. This will narrow down if the issue exist in 

1. Framework i'm dealing with
2. Grid setup

Comment: Thanks Krishnan
it seems my grid setup is working as expected, in saw 20 chrome instances.

Will dig into the framework, i'm sure they have written a TestNGRunner somewhere